# Python for matrix of a column with matrix value by a corresponding column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have these data, say d1:

```
Fruits  Person
Mango   1
Banana  1
Orange  2
Mango   1
Banana  3
Orange  1
Mango   2
Banana  3
Orange  2
Mango   2
```

I want the output to be something like this:

```
               Fruit2
Fruit1   Mango     Banana   Orange
Mango   2   0   2
Banana  0       
Orange
```

A matrix where the value being the number of distinct people who have taken `Fruit1` and `Fruit2`.  Can somebody tell me a way to do this Python. Thanks.

Comment: What `type` is d1? List, dict, etc.

Comment: Are you counting `Fruits` per `Person` or `Furit` to `Fruit`?

Comment: I'm counting fruit to fruit by distinct persons.

Comment: Well it would really help to know. Does the `Person` have any distinct value in `d1` other than the number of fruit by type? ID, name, etc.

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't. consider 1,2,3 and so on in person as unique Id numbers. Hope I'm making sense to you

Comment: I doubt it's a `dict`. The occurrences of neither `Person` nor their `Fruit` is unique. Most likely is a list of tuples. Are you trying to modify existing code or writing from scratch? If it's the former it might help sharing that code.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I'm starting from scratch as I'm new to python.  The other work I did in R and SQL server but this I cant do because of data limitations of R.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what `type` your data set is, I'm going off the assumption that it's a list of tuples based on the structure you presented.

So if `fruit1` is a list of tuples and each tuple contains the name of the fruit and the person's id. Using list comprehension, you can count the number of times the fruit and person appear together, like so:

```
import itertools

fruit1 = [
    ('Mango', 1),
    ('Banana', 1),
    ('Orange', 2),
    ('Mango', 1),
    ('Banana', 3),
    ('Orange', 1),
    ('Mango', 2),
    ('Banana', 3),
    ('Orange', 2),
    ('Mango', 2),
]

# define sort order (person, fruit)
keyfunc = lambda t: (t[1], t[0])

# sort fruit1
fruit1.sort(key=keyfunc)

# create fruit2
fruit2 = [(len(list(val)), key) for (key, val) in itertools.groupby(fruit1, keyfunc)]

# output
[
    (1, (1, 'Banana')),
    (2, (1, 'Mango')),
    (1, (1, 'Orange')),
    (2, (2, 'Mango')),
    (2, (2, 'Orange')),
    (2, (3, 'Banana')),
]
```

As you can see `fruit2` is a list of tuples, just like `fruit1` with the addition of the number of occurrences for the fruit/person. So `Person 1` had 1 entry or `Banana`, 2 for `Mango`, and so on...

It's not exactly a matrix, however, it's hard to be more specific with the information provided.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I was expecting. Just to be more I want something like a crosstab with my fruits subcategories as rows and columns and value associated be the distinct people eating it. I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: Just to make it more clear I want something like this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/13176741/3371626 in python. This is done in R.