# Table of Pairwise frequency counts in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm completely new to python and most of my work has been done in R. I would like to know how to get this question work in python. Please refer to the link for clear understanding of the question and the solution R codes. [How to calculate a table of pairwise counts from long-form data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13176741/3371626)

This is the dataset:

```
id  featureCode
5   PPLC
5   PCLI
6   PPLC
6   PCLI
7   PPL
7   PPLC
7   PCLI
8   PPLC
9   PPLC
10  PPLC
```

and this is what I want:

```
     PPLC  PCLI  PPL
PPLC  0     3     1
PCLI  3     0     1
PPL   1     1     0
```

I'd like to calculate the number of times each feature code is used with the other feature codes (the "pairwise counts" of the title).I hope this makes sense now. Please provide help on this.
Thanks..

Comment: please phrase your question in a way that can be answered.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I will try to change it but my this question : http://stackoverflow.com/q/22152856/3371626 is also based on this.

Comment: I hope now its making sense.

Answer (score 1):

This can be set up using a dictionary set up and use collections and Counter to do the analysis. However, I will show an analysis using the simplest dictionary and loop methods. Of course the actual code can be made smaller, I am deliberately showing the expanded version. My Python does not have Pandas available, so I am using the most basic Python.

```
# Assume the you have a set of tuples lst
lst.sort() # sort the list by id
mydict = {}
id = None
tags = []
for ids in lst:
  if ids[0] == id
    # Pick up the current entry
    tags.append(ids[1])
  else:
    # This is a new id
    # check the count of the previous tags.
    for elem1 in tags:
      for elem2 in tags:
        if elem1 != elem2:
          if elem1 not in mydict:
            mydict[elem1] = {}
          if elem2 not in mydict[elem1]:
            mydict[elem1][elem2] = 0
          mydict[elem1][elem2] += 1
    # This is a different id, reset the indicators for the next loop
    id = ids[0]
    tags = ids[1]        # This is a new id
else:
  # The last element of the lst has to be processed as well
  # check the count of the previous tags.
  for elem1 in tags:
    for elem2 in tags:
      if elem1 != elem2:
        if elem1 not in mydict:
          mydict[elem1] = {}
        if elem2 not in mydict[elem1]:
          mydict[elem1][elem2] = 0
        mydict[elem1][elem2] += 1


# at this point, my dict has the full dictionary count
for tag in mydict.keys():
  print tag, mydict[tag]
```

This now gives the tags with the counts and you can format your output by looping over the final dictionary, printing the keys and counts appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this in Pandas, which uses DataFrames similar to R. I am assuming you have a DataFrame `df` containing your data. (You can read the data from file using pandas.read_table. see thid: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_table.html).

First, use `groupby` to group the columns by `id`.

```
gps = df.groupby("id")
print gps.groups
Out: {5: [0, 1], 6: [2, 3], 7: [4, 5, 6], 8: [7], 9: [8], 10: [9]}
```

`groups` gives the row numbers that belong to same id.

Next, you create your target matrix having row and column names as unique values in your `featureCode`.

```
unqFet = list(set(df["featureCode"]))
final = pandas.DataFrame(columns=unqFet, index=unqFet)
final = final.fillna(0)
print final
Out: 
            PCLI PPLC PPL
     PCLI    0    0   0
     PPLC    0    0   0
     PPL     0    0   0
```

Finally, loop over your groups and increment correct values in your `final` matrix.

```
for g in gps.groups.values():
    for i in range(len(g)):
       for j in range(len(g)):
          if i != j:
              final[ df["featureCode"][g[i]] ][ df["featureCode"][g[j]] ] += 1

print final
Out:
          PCLI PPLC PPL
   PCLI    0    3   1
   PPLC    3    0   1
   PPL     1    1   0
```