# Convert data by counting number of occurrence of a combination in R

Tags: r, dataframe, frequency, reshape

I have the data in csv format with fields recipeid, ingredientname. I would like to do analysis on the data and need it formatted where one ingredientname is starting node and another as end node with 3rd column as number of occurrence of these two ingredients in recipes. Is there a command for doing this in R?

Current data looks like this:

```
recipeid | ingredientname
-------- | ---------------
01       | A
01       | B
01       | C
02       | A
02       | B
02       | D
03       | B
03       | D
```

and I want:

```
StartNode | EndNode | Occurrence
----------|---------|------------
   A      |   B     | 2
   B      |   D     | 2
   B      |   C     | 1
```

Comment: You can check the `igraph` package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate a table of pairwise counts from long-form data frame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176741/how-to-calculate-a-table-of-pairwise-counts-from-long-form-data-frame)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think this requires a graph object. You can get there by just looking at the previous row. E.g.:

```
tmp <- data.frame(
  start=ave(dat$ingredientname, dat$recipeid, FUN=function(x) c(NA,head(x,-1)) ),
  end=dat$ingredientname
)
aggregate(count ~ ., data=transform(tmp,count=1), FUN=sum)

#  start end count
#1     A   B     2
#2     B   C     1
#3     B   D     2
```

Where `dat` was:

```
dat <- read.table(text="recipeid  ingredientname
01        A
01        B
01        C
02        A
02        B
02        D
03        B
03        D",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```