# Counting pairwise occurences of characters in dataframe R

Tags: r, dataframe

This is sort of an extension to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13176741/how-to-calculate-a-table-of-pairwise-counts-from-long-form-data-frame) but I couldn't find an answer, so I'm asking fresh.

I have a dataframe, a small sample of which looks something like this:

```
X   73600000    73680000    B   43.6938
X   77160000    77290000    E1  38.7108
X   80450000    80630000    D   37.2528
X   8720000 8790000 E2  39.9114
X   99940000    100025000   B   41.2118
1   10000000    10100000    E2  46.975
1   100030000   100130000   E1  37.717
1   101080000   101330000   C   38.064
1   101390000   101755000   E2  37.9268
2   100430000   100870000   E2  41.8766
2   100870000   101000000   C   42.1769
2   101220000   101620000   E3  45.216
2   101345000   101440000   A   44.5705
2   101620000   101830000   E3  44.3948
3   100180000   100315000   E2  40.5067
3   100610000   100920000   E2  37.9716
3   101525000   101945000   E2  38.7479
3   101710000   101950000   C   38.2996
3   101945000   102260000   C   36.2844
3   10380000    10790000    D   49.1885
3   104320000   105090000   C   35.4865
3   106990000   107160000   C   38.3465
```

I want to compute pairwise occurrence of the characters in column `$4` , for each class of values in `$1`.

So for this example, my output should look like:

```
X  BE1  1
X  DE1  1
X  DE2  1
X  BE2  1
1  E1E2  1
1  CE1  1
1  CE2  2
2  E2E2  1
2  CE3  1
2  AE3  2
3  E2E2  2
3  CE2  1
3  CC  2
3  CD  2
```

I want to count the overlaps as well, as evident from the answer. 
For example, the value 3 in `$4` would yield the following combinations from the first row:
E2E2, E2E2, E2C, CC, CD, DC, CC

For my purpose, CD and DC are the same, so I would add them up to have CD  2.

What's the best way to do this in **R**?

Comment: In your desired output for *X* group, why is there no pairing of *BD* or *E1E2*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a data.table approach. You can lag the V4 vector, sort and paste the lagged and original V4 to ensure that order between each pair does not matter (e.g. CD and DC are the same), then tabulate the count for each paired occurrence.

```
dat[, .(Pairs=mapply(function(x,y) paste(sort(c(x,y)), collapse=""), 
    shift(V4), V4)[-1]), by=V1][,
        .N, by=.(V1, Pairs)]

#     V1 Pairs N
#  1:  X   BE1 1
#  2:  X   DE1 1
#  3:  X   DE2 1
#  4:  X   BE2 1
#  5:  1  E1E2 1
#  6:  1   CE1 1
#  7:  1   CE2 1
#  8:  2   CE2 1
#  9:  2   CE3 1
# 10:  2   AE3 2
# 11:  3  E2E2 2
# 12:  3   CE2 1
# 13:  3    CC 2
# 14:  3    CD 2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dat <- fread("
X   73600000    73680000    B   43.6938
X   77160000    77290000    E1  38.7108
X   80450000    80630000    D   37.2528
X   8720000     8790000     E2  39.9114
X   99940000    100025000   B   41.2118
1   10000000    10100000    E2  46.975
1   100030000   100130000   E1  37.717
1   101080000   101330000   C   38.064
1   101390000   101755000   E2  37.9268
2   100430000   100870000   E2  41.8766
2   100870000   101000000   C   42.1769
2   101220000   101620000   E3  45.216
2   101345000   101440000   A   44.5705
2   101620000   101830000   E3  44.3948
3   100180000   100315000   E2  40.5067
3   100610000   100920000   E2  37.9716
3   101525000   101945000   E2  38.7479
3   101710000   101950000   C   38.2996
3   101945000   102260000   C   36.2844
3   10380000    10790000    D   49.1885
3   104320000   105090000   C   35.4865
3   106990000   107160000   C   38.3465")
```

Comment: Gives me this error: Error in `[.data.frame`(df, , .(Pairs = mapply(function(x, y) paste(sort(c(x,  : 
  unused argument (by = V1)

Comment: you need to attach the data.table package before running the code using `library(data.table)` then convert the data.frame into a data.table using `setDT(dat)`

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is "the best", but

```
do.call(rbind,
        imap(split(exd[[4]], exd[[1]]),
             function(x, name) {
                 n <- length(x)
                 data.frame(V1 = name,
                            table(apply(cbind(x[1:(n-1)], x[2:n]),
                                        1,
                                        function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse = ""))))
             }))
##     V1 Var1 Freq
## 1.1  1  CE1    1
## 1.2  1  CE2    1
## 1.3  1 E1E2    1
## 2.1  2  AE3    2
## 2.2  2  CE2    1
## 2.3  2  CE3    1
## 3.1  3   CC    2
## 3.2  3   CD    2
## 3.3  3  CE2    1
## 3.4  3 E2E2    2
## X.1  X  BE1    1
## X.2  X  BE2    1
## X.3  X  DE1    1
## X.4  X  DE2    1
```

will work.

If you want *all* pairwise combinations you can do something like

```
do.call(rbind,
        imap(split(exd[[4]], exd[[1]]),
             function(x, name) {
                 data.frame(V1 = name,
                            table(apply(combn(as.character(x), 2),
                                        2,
                                        paste, collapse = "")))
             }))
##      V1 Var1 Freq
## 1.1   1  CE2    1
## 1.2   1  E1C    1
## 1.3   1 E1E2    1
## 1.4   1  E2C    1
## 1.5   1 E2E1    1
## 1.6   1 E2E2    1
## 2.1   2  AE3    1
## 2.2   2   CA    1
## 2.3   2  CE3    2
## 2.4   2  E2A    1
## 2.5   2  E2C    1
## 2.6   2 E2E3    2
## 2.7   2  E3A    1
## 2.8   2 E3E3    1
## 3.1   3   CC    6
## 3.2   3   CD    2
## 3.3   3   DC    2
## 3.4   3  E2C   12
## 3.5   3  E2D    3
## 3.6   3 E2E2    3
## X.1   X   BB    1
## X.2   X   BD    1
## X.3   X  BE1    1
## X.4   X  BE2    1
## X.5   X   DB    1
## X.6   X  DE2    1
## X.7   X  E1B    1
## X.8   X  E1D    1
## X.9   X E1E2    1
## X.10  X  E2B    1
```

Comment: I realized that's not exactly what I want to do. Your answer is not what I'd expect to get, as I've posted along as well. I want to go from the first row of my dataframe to the last row, and count the pairwise occurrence of $4 elements.

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea what you're actually trying to do. I'll leave this answer up for now, but I no longer understand your goal. Why (for example) is the last row of your expected result `3  CD  2`?

Comment: Because if you count the pairwise occurrence from top to bottom at 3(allowing them to overlap), you get the following combinations: E2E2, E2E2, E2C, CC, CD, DC, CC. For my goal, CD and DC are the same, so I add them up. I thought it would be clear with the example answer, but I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see you don't actually want all pairwise occurrences, just those that are adjacent. I've updated the answer.